# Does windows authentication work even if the AD server cannot be reached?

Tags: sql-server, authentication

The basic question is this, if our Windows service uses Windows Authentication for connections to SQL Server, and then because of a network disconnect, SQL server and/or the client machine cannot reach AD to authorize or authenticate, will our service still be able to connect to SQL Server and operate?
I’ve tried it and it seems to work, but we are concerned if it will work even after a few days of being disconnected or after server reboots and the like.
The alternative would be to use SQL Server Authentication, but we would rather not have to deal with potentially exposing and having to protect the password on the client computer. This computer may be in a remote location with little supervision.  SQL Server would typically be running on this same remote computer.
And for the follow up questions, does it matter which edition of SQL Server we use?  Does it matter that both SQL Server and the service are running on the same computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If AD connection is lost, existing SQL connections will keep working (at least for some time), and connection pools will be still available (again, for some time). However, I wouldn't get too comfortable with this, because these time spans might depend on settings outside of a typical DBA' reach.

Alternatives are:

1. Use an AD proxy. Depends on circumstances, might not be always viable;
2. Use local user accounts instead of AD. Works always.